# Logstash Origin connector for StreamSets

Tags: streamsets

Is it possible to build directly a pipeline using Logstash as origin and Cassandra as destination. If not, how could be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not exactly a way to take data directly from Logstash. StreamSets is more of a replacement for Logstash than an integration point, so I'd probably suggest that you consider using StreamSets to pick data up from wherever Logstash is sourcing it, and send it directly to Cassandra. That said, if you can send from Logstash to a file on the same server as StreamSets (or any location that a StreamSets origin can pick up from), you can use StreamSets to move the data into Cassandra.

Comment: The question was asked on the StreamSets mailing list. Copied the answer here for the benefit of the SO community.